# Mathematica doesn't solve the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

I need to find primitive function to:

$$f(x)=\frac{(168-26\sin{x}+\sin^2{x})^2}{6-5\sin{x}+\sin^2{x}}$$

I'm very new to Mathematica and its syntax, but I think I wrote the code correctly.

```
f[x_]:=(168-26*Sin[x]+(Sin^2)[x])^2/(6-5*Sin[x]+(Sin^2)[x])
Integrate[f[x],x]
```

It doesn't however want to solve the integral. I just get back the integral symbol with my f(x) expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If yo write Sin[x]^2 instead of Sin^2[x] you will get an answer:

```
f[x_] := (168 - 26*Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2)^2/(6 - 5*Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2)
Integrate[f[x], x]
```

[image]

Comment: Big thank you! Can I ask how do I know if I'm using correct syntax? Because I just pull my hair out most of the time, because I'm not aware the syntax is not correct

Comment: **Can I ask how do I know if I'm using correct syntax?** Unfortunately, `Evaluation->Analyze cell or ->Analyze notebook` does not check for such syntax errors.  This is something you just have to be careful about when writing code.   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0HNf.png)  Mathematica is very flexible language, it allows you to write anything you want, and since it is dynamic language, errors will show up when you run the code.  This is common problem in all dynamics languages and not just Mathematica. You will find the errors when you run the code. No static analysis.

Comment: @LennyWhite Strictly speaking, `Sin^2[x]` is not a syntax error. It is a valid expression as an expression. However, there are no semantics attached to the expression that give it any meaning or value.  Because it is a syntactically valid expression, there is no way to ask Mathematica to indicate it does not express what you had in mind. To help you learn, try using **ctrl-equal** at the beginning. It will **try** to translate normal math input into valid Mathematic expressions. Entering "integrate (168-26*Sin[x]+Sin^2[x])^2/(6-5*Sin[x]+Sin^2[x])" works, if `()` around Sin^2 is omitted

Comment: MMA works by replacing parts using replacement rules. It replaces as long as there is anything to replace. Now if there is a rule for e.g. Sin[Pi/2] it is replaced by 1. Or for he integration of Sin[x]^2. However, if there is no rule for e-g.:  Sin^2[x] there is nothing replaced and the whole expression is returned. Therefore, if you get the original expression back, there is no rule. However, you may add a rule yourself.